# I can not catch exception in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii2

I am using Yii framework and have written code below. When there is no entry for a specific id it gives  `Error: Call to a member function delete() on a non-object` which is a `yii\base\ErrorException` indicated in debug mode. The problem is that I am not able to catch this exception despite my inclusion of `yii\base\ErrorException` and specify it catch block. What is the problem here?

```
            use yii\base\ErrorException;

            try {
                $model = BranchUser::findOne($_GET['id']);
                $model->delete();
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            } catch (ErrorException $e) {
                return $this->redirect(['site/error']);
                // Error, rollback transaction
                throw $e;
                // print_r($model->getErrors());

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a fatal error and it is not possible to recover from it.

You should check that `$model` is something else than `null` before you try to use it.

```
if ($model === null) {
    return $this->redirect(['site/error']);
}
```

[Such errors are catchable in PHP 7.0](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_exceptions_for_php7), so that's good.

Comment: I like your answer, but if the question was, "How can throw an exception if findOne don't find anything?"

Comment: @IvanButtinoni Then you throw an exception instead of returning. :)

Comment: yes, that was the idea, but at first sight there's no event/behaviour that can ovrerride the conduct of "findOne" :(